# c++ curl returns 413 request entity too large however the post size is much less than max size

Tags: php, c++, curl

I noticed that some of my posts weren't submitted so I saw the output from curl in the c++ code and it gave

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
  The requested resource<br />/receiver.php<br />
  does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
  the request exceeds the capacity limit.
  </body></html>
```

I tested the max size allowed for post requests on the php side with this :

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

and I got : 20M

then got the size of the post being sent from the c++ code like this :

```
void send_request(string url, string field,string data) {
string post_req = field + "=" + data;
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_req.c_str());
cout << "post size : " << post_req.size() << endl;
curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

the post was only 1059544 bytes = 1M
it's far from 20M

where is the problem in php side ? or c++ code ?

Comment: why the down vote ?

Comment: which webserver are you using? what is it's request size limit? Where's your php code? we need a [mcve]

Comment: as I said I printed post_max_size value on the php side and it gave me 20M , my php is a free awardspace hosting . I searched for their request size limit but didn't find anything , I may contact the support as the php result may be wrong

Comment: `post_max_size` is the maximum post request size php will accept, there will be at least a web server if not more between your application and php which will have their own rules

Comment: I submitted a ticket now and waiting for their response , I think you are right and I have to buy a paid account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is neither in C++ nor in PHP.

you have some server in front of PHP (usually `nginx` or `apache` for unix-style servers, or microsoft's `IIS` for windows-servers, albeit other servers also exists), the problem is almost certainly a configuration option in that server.

less commonly, it's also *possible* that your server has a firewall generating that response, but it's much more likely to be some server software, as mentioned above.

also, unrelated, but there's a bug in your c++ code: both data and field should be url encoded, they're apparently not.